# Import untrustworthy image into docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, virtualization

Is it possible to import images from untrustworthy sources using the "docker import" command without threatening the host or other docker containers?

If not: Can a "tar" image (or any other format) be sanatized to be imported without harming? What are the main points to consider?

Specially: does the image file ("tar" or what ever) can contain any (docker) commands  that can be harmfull?

Edit: I tried to investigate the "tar" export. For me it looks like it doesn't contain any operations that will be run on the host. But of course I still don't know if they can optionally.

Comment: If they were harmful to your machine, they would also be harmful to the host that generated them... And generally, the docker executable itself shouldn't be running under a super-user account anyway. If you aren't using volume mounts and limiting the cpu/memory of said container, should be *safer*

Comment: I'm concerned that an attacker may could modify the image to attack the machine importing it.

Comment: You should be able to import the image, but if the container isn't actually ran, there is nothing but metadata and compressed, not executable files for the image on your machine. Once imported, you can do `docker history --no-trunc <image>` to see what the image will actually do when ran

Comment: Can an image harm other containers when be run? I thought the containers are isolated from the host and each other?

Comment: Again, should only be possible if you do a volume mount for the docker socket file.

Comment: If there's a kernel-level local privilege escalation issue, a running container can exploit it.  There's various things that you could consider "unsavory" but not "dangerous" that a container could do (is there a secret path in its HTTP service that's a control node for a botnet?).  It is probably safer than running something directly on your host, but if you're asking the question, I wouldn't consider it "safe".